# How to make a multi-line equation fit in a single column of a two-column document

Tags: spacing, equations

I am trying to suit a formula to a two-column style document using `cases` in the `flalign`.
It nearly fits if an unnecessary space would not prevent. Is their any option to remove it?

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
E_{\perp,diff}=
\begin{cases}
E_{g,meas}&\cdot(1.020-0.254\cdot k+0.0123\\
&\cdot\sin\gamma_S)  \quad \text{for k $\le$ 0.3}\\
E_{g,meas}&\cdot(1.400-1.749\cdot k+0.177\\ 
&\cdot\sin\gamma_S)      \quad \text{for 0.3 $<$ k $<$ 0.78}\\
E_{g,meas}&\cdot(0.486\cdot k-0.182\\ 
&\cdot \sin\gamma_S) \quad \text{for k $\geq$ 0.78}
\end{cases}
\end{flalign} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `flalign` (I see it too often abused) nor `cases`, but `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E_{\perp,\mathrm{diff}}=
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  E_{g,\mathrm{meas}}
    &\cdot(1.020-0.254\cdot k+0.0123\\
    &\cdot\sin\gamma_S)  \quad \text{for $k\le 0.3$}\\
  E_{g,\mathrm{meas}}
    &\cdot(1.400-1.749\cdot k+0.177\\
    &\cdot\sin\gamma_S)      \quad \text{for $0.3 < k < 0.78$}\\
  E_{g,\mathrm{meas}}
    &\cdot(0.486\cdot k-0.182\\
    &\cdot \sin\gamma_S) \quad \text{for $k \geq 0.78$}
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd split into two parts: one with the main information, the other with the complicated things.

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
E_{\perp,\mathrm{diff}}=E_{g,\mathrm{meas}}\varphi(k,\gamma_S)\\
\varphi(k,\gamma_S)=
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  1.020-0.254k+0.0123\sin\gamma_S\\
    \hfill\text{for $k\le 0.3$}\\[1ex]
  1.400-1.749k+0.177\sin\gamma_S\\
    \hfill\text{for $0.3 < k < 0.78$}\\[1ex]
  0.486k-0.182\sin\gamma_S\\
    \hfill\text{for $k \geq 0.78$}
  \end{array}
  \right.\notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that inserting a line break at a multiplicative location is inferior to breaking the line at an additive (or subtractive) location. Moreover, I think that a `cases` environment is not particularly well suited for the formula at hand. I'd use a basic `\left\{ ... \right.` construct and provide an additional line break in each of the two subformulas in order to separate the math part more clearly from the `for...` condition.

[image]

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E_{\perp,\textit{diff}}=
\left\{
\begin{split}
&E_{g,\textit{meas}}\cdot(1.020-0.254 k\\
&\qquad +0.0123\sin\gamma_S)\\
&\qquad \text{for $k \le 0.3$}\\
&E_{g,\textit{meas}}\cdot(1.400-1.749 k\\
&\qquad +0.177\sin\gamma_S)\\
&\qquad \text{for $0.3 < k < 0.78$}\\
&E_{g,\textit{meas}}\cdot(0.486k-0.182\sin\gamma_S) \\
&\qquad \text{for $k \geq 0.78$}
\end{split}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine/modify the `cases` environment

```
\makeatletter
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{}} % adjust 2pt to suit your need
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{}} % adjust 2pt to suit your need
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
E_{\perp,diff}=
\begin{cases}
E_{g,meas}&\cdot(1.020-0.254\cdot k+0.0123\\
&\cdot\sin\gamma_S)  \quad \text{for k $\le$ 0.3}\\
E_{g,meas}&\cdot(1.400-1.749\cdot k+0.177\\ 
&\cdot\sin\gamma_S)      \quad \text{for 0.3 $<$ k $<$ 0.78}\\
E_{g,meas}&\cdot(0.486\cdot k-0.182\\ 
&\cdot \sin\gamma_S) \quad \text{for k $\geq$ 0.78}
\end{cases}
\end{flalign} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: And when `cases` is needed in the original form?

Comment: An adverbial clause without the main clause sets me at sea for a while. Hope I understand what you tried to ask. Here goes; make a local array environment.\[ \arraystretch}{1.2}
E_{\perp,diff} = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{}}
      content\end{array}
\] Thanks for the hint. Obviously there are rooms for improvement to my answer --- still learning.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reducing the font size to `\small` (locally) and replacing the brace with bullets, using the `\mathllap` command from `mathtools` to have right-alignment of the conditions:

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

{\small%
\begin{align}\label{eqA}
\mathrlap{ E_{ ⊥ ,\,\mathrm{diff}}=} \\
\notag &\! \begin{aligned}
  \bullet\enspace &E_{g,\,\mathrm{meas}} · (1.020-0.254 · k+0.0123 · \sinγ_S) & \\
 &\hspace*{-2em} & \mathllap{\text{for}\enspace k ≤ 0.3\quad}\\
  \bullet\enspace & E_{g,\,\mathrm{meas}} · (1.400-1.749 · k+0.177 · \sinγ_S) & \\
 & & \mathllap{\text{for}\enspace 0.3 < k < 0.78\quad} \\
  \bullet\enspace & E_{g,\,\mathrm{meas}} · (0.486 · k-0.182 · \sinγ_S ) \\
 & & \mathllap{\text{for}\enspace k \geq 0.78\quad}
  \end{aligned}\
\end{align}
    }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Variant, with the equation number on the first line and normalsize:

```
\documentclass[3p,times,12pt,draft,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

{%
\begin{align}\label{eqA}
\mathrlap{ E_{ ⊥ ,\,\mathrm{diff}}=} \\
\notag &\! \begin{aligned}
  \bullet\enspace &E_{g,\,\mathrm{meas}} · (1.020-0.254 · k+0.0123 · \sinγ_S) \hskip-1.5em & \\
 &\hspace*{-2em} & \mathllap{\text{for}\enspace k ≤ 0.3}\\
  \bullet\enspace & E_{g,\,\mathrm{meas}} · (1.400-1.749 · k+0.177 · \sinγ_S)\hskip-1.5em & \\
 & & \mathllap{\text{for}\enspace 0.3 < k < 0.78} \\
  \bullet\enspace & E_{g,\,\mathrm{meas}} · (0.486 · k-0.182 · \sinγ_S ) \\
 & & \mathllap{\text{for}\enspace k \geq 0.78}
  \end{aligned}\
\end{align}
    }%

\end{document}
```

[image]